# Class method return iterator

Tags: python, iterator

I implemented an iterator class as following:

```
import numpy as np
import time


class Data:

    def __init__(self, filepath):
        # Computationaly expensive
        print("Computationally expensive")
        time.sleep(10)
        print("Done!")

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return np.zeros((2,2)), np.zeros((2,2))


count = 0
for batch_x, batch_y in Data("hello.csv"):
    print(batch_x, batch_y)
    count = count + 1

    if count > 5:
        break


count = 0
for batch_x, batch_y in Data("hello.csv"):
    print(batch_x, batch_y)
    count = count + 1

    if count > 5:
        break
```

However the constructor is computationally expensive, and the for loop might be called multiple times. For example, in above code the constructor is called twice (each for loop create a new Data object).

How do I separate constructor and iterator? I am hoping to have the following code, where constructor is called once only:

```
data = Data(filepath)

for batch_x, batch_y in data.get_iterator():
    print(batch_x, batch_y)

for batch_x, batch_y in data.get_iterator():
    print(batch_x, batch_y)
```

Comment: I mean... what's wrong with the above code? The construction and iteration are already separate. Just reuse the object created by calling `Data()` instead of creating a new one. Do you have an example of your current code where the constructor is being called twice and you don't want it to?

Comment: I updated the question. In the first version, constructor is called twice.

Comment: Don't understand why `data.get_iterator()`.  What's wrong if you write just `for batch_x, batch_y in data:`?

Comment: @TomášCerha: it calls the constructor `__init__`, which is computationally expensive.

Comment: I added an answer with a bunch of variants, which one is the "best" really depends on the specifics of your case - what part is "computationally expensive", whether or not afterwards data is all available in a list or other iterable object in memory, or if you're still fetching the data on demand somehow.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate over an iterable object directly, `for..in` doesn't require anything else:

```
data = Data(filepath)

for batch_x, batch_y in data:
    print(batch_x, batch_y)

for batch_x, batch_y in data:
    print(batch_x, batch_y)
```

That said, depending on how you implement `__iter__()`, this could be buggy.

E.g.:

#### Bad

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self._items = load_items(filepath)
        self._i = 0
    def __iter__(self): return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self._i >= len(self._items): # Or however you check if data is available
            raise StopIteration
        result = self._items[self._i]
        self._i += 1
        return result
```

Because then you couldn't iterate over the same object twice, as `self._i` would still point at the end of the loop.

#### Good-ish

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self._items = load_items(filepath)
    def __iter__(self):
        self._i = 0
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self._i >= len(self._items):
            raise StopIteration
        result = self._items[self._i]
        self._i += 1
        return result
```

This resets the index every time you're about to iterate, fixing the above. This won't work if you're nesting iteration over the same object.

#### Better

To fix that, keep the iteration state in a separate iterator object:

```
class Data:
    class Iter:
        def __init__(self, data):
            self._data = data
            self._i = 0
        def __next__(self):
            if self._i >= len(self._data._items): # check for available data
                raise StopIteration
            result = self._data._items[self._i]
            self._i = self._i + 1
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self._items = load_items(filepath)
    def __iter__(self): 
        return self.Iter(self)
```

This is the most flexible approach, but it's unnecessarily verbose if you can use either of the below ones.

#### Simple, using `yield`

If you use Python's generators, the language will take care of keeping track of iteration state for you, and it should do so correctly even when nesting loops:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self._items= load_items(filepath)
    def __iter__(self): 
        for it in self._items: # Or whatever is appropriate
            yield return it
```

#### Simple, pass-through to underlying iterable

If the "computationally expensive" part is loading all the data into memory, you can just use the cached data directly.

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self._items = load_items(filepath)
    def __iter__(self): 
        return iter(self._items)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new instance of `Data`, create a second class `IterData` that contains an `__init__` method that runs a process which is not as computationally expensive as instantiating `Data`. Then, create a `classmethod` in `Data` as an alternative constructor for `IterData`:

```
class IterData:
  def __init__(self, filepath):
     #only pass the necessary data
  def __iter__(self):
     #implement iter here

class Data:
  def __init__(self, filepath):
    # Computationaly expensive
  @classmethod
  def new_iter(cls, filepath):
    return IterData(filepath)

results = Data.new_iter('path')
for batch_x, batch_y in results:
   pass
```